# how to add animation to D3 custom Radios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, d3.js

I have radios aligned on an arch.

I would like to add a transition that slides the selected inner blue dot along the arch to the newly selected radio.

[image]

I have a working demo setup.
[WORKING DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-d3-pie-chart-forked-i2r1j?file=/src/PieHooks.js)

Answer (score 4):

See a solution in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrovinsky/fymqohd0/) (click on the blue button):

Just put the button in a "g" and rotate it with transition:

```
const button = d3.select("#button");
let angle = 60;

button.on("click", () => {
 angle = -angle;
 button.transition().duration(1000).attr("transform", `translate(${cX}, ${cY}) rotate(${angle})`);
});
```

Comment: i need it to work when I selected a unselected radio. this is only working with the already selected radio

Comment: also can you use my demo?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use **animateMotion** along the path:

```html
<svg width="300" height="200">
    <path fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3"
      d="M 20,20 A 100,100 0 0 0 220,20" />
      <circle r="10" fill="white" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3">
        <animateMotion dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"
        path="M 20,20 A 100,100 0 0 0 220,20 A 100,100 1 1 1 20,20" />
    </circle>
</svg>
```